# Why is there an ambiguous in my code of my function that count the number of 1s in a binary representation of decimal n

Tags: c++, binary, counter

I need to have a function that counts the number of 1s in a binary representaion of a decimal n. But while I'm compile it, it gives the following error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJYTa.png)

Here is my code for that

```
int countBits(unsigned int n){
  if(n%2 == 0){
    return countBits(n/2);
  }else if(n%2 != 0){
    return 1 + countBits(floor(n/2));
  }else if(n == 1){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

and here is how I called it in main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void outputBinary(unsigned int x);
int countBits(int n);

int main(){
  int a = 21;
  int b = countBits(a);
  cout << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How to fix it？Thanks

Comment: By the way, our exercise ask as to use the fact that if n is even, the number of 1s in the representation of n is the same as that in n/2; if n is odd, the number of 1s is one more than that in floor(n/2). And the function should be recursive

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question. Please no images and please no links unless absolutely necessary. Images are not necessary to post text

Comment: itCounter.cpp:20:16: error: call to 'countBits' is ambiguous
    return 1 + countBits(floor(n/2));
               ^~~~~~~~~
bitCounter.cpp:7:5: note: candidate function
int countBits(int n);
    ^
bitCounter.cpp:16:5: note: candidate function
int countBits(unsigned int n){

Comment: Your function declaration/prototype is `int countBits(int n);` but the definition has `unsigned int` i.e. `int countBits(unsigned int n) {...}`. Fix the prototype or the definition.

Comment: After I fixed the problem of ambiguity there is a Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @HongyanWu You have an **infinite recursion**, since in your `if-else` branches, only the first two are reachable. Namely, `n % 2` is always either zero or non-zero. You should add something as `if (n < 2) return n;` at the beginning.

Comment: Also, have a look at GDB or any other debugging tool. It comes handy when you're stuck trying to debug code that doesn't work or doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: I have changed the prototype to int countBits(unsigned int n)

Comment: BTW, `floor(n/2)` makes no sense. `n/2` is an integral number by itself, so why "flooring" it?

Comment: That's given in our instruction which said that  if n is odd, the number of 1s is one more than that in floor(n/2)

Comment: @HongyanWu But `n/2` "floors" itself. This is integer division. If you write it as an arithmetic expression, then _n/2_ is not an integer if _n_ is odd. One can say that `n/2` equals `floor(` _n/2_ `)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined and declared `countBits` in two different ways. In your first code snippet, you have `int countBits(unsigned int n)` (with an *unsigned int* argument) but, in your second snippet you give a 'forward declaration' as `int countBits(int n);` - with a (signed) `int` argument.

The compiler doesn't know which form to use in your call.

You should fix the code so that the two function signatures are the same - most likely, you should change the declaration (in your second snippet) to match the first, so change it to this: `int countBits(unsigned int n);`.

Also, your `countBits` function will call itself endlessly, because one of the first two `if`/`else if` blocks will ***always*** be true (even when the argument given is `0` or `1`) - this will end up crashing the program. To fix this, test for `0` or `1` **first**:

```cpp
int countBits(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return countBits(n / 2);
    }
    else {// if (n % 2 != 0) {
        return 1 + countBits(floor(n / 2));
    }
}
```

Further, you can 'merge' the first two tests into one:

```cpp
int countBits(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return countBits(n / 2);
    }
    else {
        return 1 + countBits(n / 2); // don't need "floor" for integer division
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Thank you! That will help me a lot

Comment: Note that it can be further simplified: `if(n == 0) return 0; return n%2 + countBits(n/2);`

Comment: @Damien Indeed ... but I didn't want to throw too many changes at the OP all in one go. Sometimes, it's best to allow folks to learn at a steady pace. There are also *far* more efficient ways to count the set bits in a given `unsigned int` (you can search Stack Overflow for some very nice but complicated ones using bit shifts and masks).